# Does social media have measurable impacts on our brain?

Tags: neurology, social-media

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Social Networking harmful to mind or body?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6503/is-social-networking-harmful-to-mind-or-body)

Many claims are being made on social media affecting everything from attentionspan to ability to comperhend complex ideas. Are there any conclusive evidences for such claims?

Comment: Yes. Or What? No? Hm. Uh?

Comment: Russian corners of YouTube are full of "Victim of VKontakte" videos [VKontakte is a Russian Facebook], which are incredibly moronic videos people post about themselves to social networking sites. Not a proof, but definitely some evidence of correllation